# I am confused with the output of command 'du' in Linux

Tags: linux

I create a file named file.o, i want to check the size of the file.o file.

`du -h file.o ====> 4.0K`

`du -b file.o ====> 1120`

according to `du -b file.o`, i get to know file.o is 1120bytes large. But why `du -h file.o` outputs 4.0K (means 4*1024 bytes)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The file is smaller, but it takes one whole 4.0K block on the disk (you can have only one file in one block). If its byte size were (for example) 5678 Bytes, it would occupy two 4.0K blocks, i.e. 8.0K.

`du -b` prints sizes in bytes, overriding the default block size.

Answer (score 10):

To add to eumiro's answer, the block size can be different for each filesystem/partition.

You can find a filesystem's block size using `tune2fs -l /dev/<disk> | grep '^Block size'` or `stat -c "%o" <file on the disk>`.